# C# await task Console splash

Tags: .net, task, console-application

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{ print(); }

static async void print()
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Console.WriteLine("3");
            Debug.Write("3");
        });
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { }
    Console.Read();
}
```

Console splashed without any error occurs!

Answer (score 0):

It happens because `print` method is called in parallel so `main` goes on and since there is nothing else to do, it returns. After `main` is finished program exits.

If you want it to wait for `print` method, change it so it returns `Task` instead of `void` and then wait that task in `Main` method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{ print().Wait(); }

static async Task print() {...}
```